# why can I enable PCIe MSI on ubuntu 15.04(kernel 3.19.0-42-generic)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pci-e

I try to enable PCI MSI with

```
nvec = pci_enable_msi_range(dev, 1, 4);
```

but nvec is alway return 1 vector(I'm sure my PCIe endpoint enable MSI capability). I find the original IRQ=17 had mapped into 109. So I guest the MSI works. But, just only one vector.
I trace the kernel source and find the problem is cause at

```
pci_msi_setup_msi_irqs(struct pci_dev *dev, int nvec, int type)
```

My kernel doesn't define CONFIG_PCI_MSI_IRQ_DOMAIN. so the pci_msi_setup_msi_irqs is defined as arch_setup_msi_irqs

```
#define pci_msi_setup_msi_irqs      arch_setup_msi_irqs

int __weak arch_setup_msi_irqs(struct pci_dev *dev, int nvec, int type)
{
    struct msi_desc *entry;
    int ret;

    /*
     * If an architecture wants to support multiple MSI, it needs to
     * override arch_setup_msi_irqs()
     */
    if (type == PCI_CAP_ID_MSI && nvec > 1)
        return 1;

...
}
```

I think that is the root cause why my MSI fail.

My question are

1. should I try to define CONFIG_PCI_MSI_IRQ_DOMAIN? where can I config it?(I can not find it in kernel menuconfig)
2. what is MSI IRQ Domain?
3. or should I need to override arch_setup_msi_irqs()?

Comment: Which arch are you using? Does it override `arch_setup_msi_irqs()`?

Comment: I use x86_64. I didn't override 'arch_setup_msi_irqs()'. Should I need to implement it? why?

Comment: The x86 arch code overrides `arch_setup_msi_irqs()`. Search there.

Comment: I find the `arch_setup_msi_irqs` function in \arch\x86\kernel\x86_init.c
And it will call the `native_setup_msi_irqs` function in \arch\x86\kernel\apic\msi.c

Unfortunately, It still always return 1 when nvec > 1 (just like previous one)
But, the comment in source code is different
 `/* Multiple MSI vectors only supported with interrupt remapping */`
I have no idea how to do. 
Could you guide a direction for me?
Thank you.

Comment: Did CONFIG_IRQ_REMAP & setting INTEL_IOMMU/AMD_IOMMU work !! ?